# table client has no column named height

Tags: java, android, sqlite, runtime-error

I'm getting this error from my logcat.

```
03-19 08:41:48.174: E/Database(271): Error inserting height=53.0 status=OBESE bmi=38.290850836596654 contact_num=00000000000 address=usa age=21 gender=female weight_client=153.0 full_name=claire
03-19 08:41:48.174: E/Database(271): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table client has no column named height: , while compiling: INSERT INTO client(height, status, bmi, contact_num, address, age, gender, weight_client, full_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

When I'm using an emulator, that happens. But when I try it on my device, data insertion seems to not have a problem. I'm confused on why this happens. Can somebody please explain it to me?

Also, here is the code from my `DBAdapter` and from my `ViewClient.class` which might help in pinpointing as to where the problem lies.

Code from my `DBAdapter`:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "client";
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
public static final String FULLNAME = "full_name";
public static final String GENDER = "gender";
public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String AGE = "age";
public static final String CONTACT_NUM = "contact_num";
public static final String HEIGHT = "height";
public static final String WEIGHT = "weight_client";
public static final String BMI = "bmi";
public static final String STATUS = "status";

String sq_clients = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
                        "(" + CLIENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        FULLNAME + " text not null, " +
                        GENDER + " text not null, " +
                        ADDRESS + " text not null, " +
                        AGE + " integer not null, " +
                        CONTACT_NUM + " text not null, " +
                        HEIGHT + " integer not null, " +
                        WEIGHT + " integer not null, " +
                        BMI + " integer not null, " +
                        STATUS + " text not null);";
```

ViewClient.java:

```
package com.example.********;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DatabaseViewClient extends Activity {

    private EditText fullname;
    private EditText address_client;
    private EditText age_client;
    private EditText gender;
    private EditText contactNum_client;
    private EditText height_client;
    private EditText weight_client;
    private Button btnSaveCustomer;

    int current_client_id;
    String current_client_fullname;
    String current_client_address;
    String current_client_contactnum;
    String current_client_height;
    String current_client_weight;
    String current_client_gender;
    int current_client_age;
    String current_client_bmi, current_client_status;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addclient);

        fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gender);
        age_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age_client);
        address_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address_client);
        contactNum_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactNum_client);
        height_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_client);
        weight_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_client);

        btnSaveCustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        current_client_id = extras.getInt("CLIENT_ID");
        current_client_fullname = extras.getString("FULLNAME");
        current_client_gender = extras.getString("GENDER");
        current_client_age = extras.getInt("AGE");
        current_client_address = extras.getString("ADDRESS");
        current_client_contactnum = extras.getString("CONTACT_NUM");
        current_client_height = extras.getString("HEIGHT");
        current_client_weight = extras.getString("WEIGHT");
        current_client_bmi = extras.getString("BMI");
        current_client_status = extras.getString("STATUS");

        fullname.setText(current_client_fullname);
        gender.setText(current_client_gender);
        address_client.setText(current_client_address);
        contactNum_client.setText(current_client_contactnum);
        height_client.setText(current_client_height);
        weight_client.setText(current_client_weight);


        fullname.setKeyListener(null);
        gender.setKeyListener(null);
        age_client.setKeyListener(null);
        address_client.setKeyListener(null);
        contactNum_client.setKeyListener(null);
        height_client.setKeyListener(null);
        weight_client.setKeyListener(null);

        btnSaveCustomer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HEIGHT + " **integer** not null, "

And you´re doing: inserting height=**53.0**

So I guess this may be the reason

UPD - I see that you have weight as integer and don´t have problems, so should be something different then :)

Comment: I already removed the "not null" part in my query, but still it mentions the same problem.

Comment: I think if it works on device, then nothing to find out. Emulator, as said, is not the best tool.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on the device and not on the emulator, it works. This probably isn't what you want to hear, but the emulator is notoriously buggy and inconsistent. I've had similar questions myself where the emulator and device act differently - the "solution" is not to use the emulator.

Essentially, if your question is along the lines of "on the emulator X, but on the device Y," or simply "why does X not work on the emulator," then the emulator is most likely the problem. There's no use addressing bugs specific to the emulator anyway.

Comment: thank you for your replies and sharing a bit of your time. I guess I just got panicky after facing that error.